# Enviar formulario sem carregar a pagina via json

Tags: jquery, json, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um site e estou usando laravel, e preciso enviar uma form sem atualizar a pagina, estou usando jquery porem n sei muito como se faz alguem pode me ajudar?.

formulario html

```
<form>
   {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="user impar"><figure><img src="img/users/Profiles/Sem_FT.png"></figure><span class="nickname">1<span class="cartaoAmarelo cartaoAmarelo0"></span><button name="desafiado" type="hidden" value="20">DESAFIAR!</button> <p></p></span></div>
</form>
```

javascript para enviar ao banco de dados

```
function desafio(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data=$(this).serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
         url: "desafio",
         type: "post",
         dataType: "json",
         data: data,   
       })
       .done(function() {
         alert( "success" );
       })
       .fail(function() {
         alert( "error" );
       })
       .always(function() {

       });
    })
}
```

Ele envia porem recarrega a pagina e envia para o local errado ele faz tipo se fosse uma requisição `GET`
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ele da:

```
http://localhost/vitalento/public/jogar?_token=6H5lGaH436ibjo41uALi45Qct08aLocK3DObU9y6&desafiado=20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa evitar que o retorno da função submit seja `true`. Para isso, basta seguir o exempo abaixo, adicionando um return false na sua função:

```
function desafio(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data=$(this).serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
         url: "desafio",
         type: "post",
         dataType: "json",
         data: data,   
       })
       .done(function() {
         alert( "success" );
       })
       .fail(function() {
         alert( "error" );
       })
       .always(function() {

       });
       return false;
    })
}
```